# What advantages does Block Programming Environment have over High Level Programming Language

Tags: programming-languages

What advantages do block programming environments like App Inventor have over high level programming languages like Python or Java?

Comment: What do you think? What aspects of these styles of language have you considered? What aspects of programming langauges have you covered in your classes that might be advantages or disadvantages of these particular styles of languages? Might an advantage in one context might be a disadvantage in other contexts?

Comment: For those not familiar with the UK education system, GCSEs are national exams taken at age 16. Students typically study about ten subjects to age 16, before specializing in about three subjects from 16-18.

Comment: All I know that they are easier to learn and understand but I can't write an essay on that.

Comment: Could I talk about the fact that the graphics are already presented?

Comment: Are you asked to reproduce propaganda that you can read about on the web pages devoted to such languages, or is your opinion supposed to be based on some sort of experience with programming languages? Or are you supposed to repeat something you heard in class that the teacher said? I find it a bit disturbing that anyone would ask such a question on an exam.

Comment: This wasn't an exam question it was just a homework question and we could use both experience that we gained in class and online help.

Comment: Easier to learn and understand is a good place to start. What makes them that way? What makes other languages harder to learn and/or understand? Why is easier to learn an advantage? (Brain surgery is very advantageous but very difficult to learn, for example. But riding a bike is fairly easy to learn and also advantageous.) Are there examples of disadvantages of traditional languages that you can turn into advantages of block programming environments?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this but I know some computer science education types that do a lot with Scratch and I would be willing to bet that people in the field have done studies that compared Scratch with other options. Does any one know of some papers that give some interesting results on the matter?

Answer (score 1):

Developing complex software is completely different from writing small programs.

Complex individual systems are usually elements of complex ecosystems of software and hardware platforms, interfaces, languages, and even extra-computational factors. In creating those kinds of systems the choice of languages that use visual metaphors would probably be detrimental, not beneficial, and that is why professional software developers are happy that the languages they use are "spartan".

On the other hand, if your intention is to reduce the learning curve for begginers that are not going to be professional developers of any kind, then you can begin to talk about the benefits of those "soft" languages.

Comment: Two additional observations: is it possible that an amateur programmer, using some Scratch-like environment, creates a killer app? Of course it is, but that will always be the exception, not the rule. Does that mean that I personally disdain playful programming environments? Definitely not, as long as we take them for what they truly are.